# Of these functions that find unique items in a list, why one of them not return a 9?

Tags: javascript

I've implemented three different functions to find unique items in a list in order to compare result speed.

The speed tests are all successful, but oddly, Method 3 does not include the number 9 in it's list of original list items. **Why not?**

It's safe to say that since the list is made up of 10,000 random number strings between 1 & 11, all of the numbers will always exist, so this result is consistent for tests.

**Generating List:**

```
var ls = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {

    ls.push((Math.round((Math.random() * 10) + 1)).toString());

}
```

**First Method:**

```
var uniques = function uniques(list) {

    for (var uniqls = [],
    it = -1,
    length = list.length,
    fi = uniques.findindex;

    ++it < length;

    (fi(list, list[it]) - it) || uniqls.push(list[it]));

    return uniqls;
};

Object.defineProperty(uniques, 'findindex', {

    'configurable': true,
        'enumerable': true,
        'writable': true,
        'value': function (ls, node) {

        for (var it = -1, length = ls.length;
        (++it < length) && (node !== ls[it]););
        return (length - it) ? it : -1;

    }
});
```

**Third Method:**

```
function sortUnique(ls) {
    
    var sorted_arr = ls.sort();
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ls.length - 1; i++) {
        
        if (sorted_arr[i + 1] !== sorted_arr[i]) {
            
            results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
            
        }
        
    }
    
    return results;
}
```

**Test & Time:**

```
console.time("M1 loop");

console.log("M1 Unique" + uniques(ls));

console.timeEnd("M1 loop");

console.time("M3 loop");

console.log("M3 Unique" + (sortUnique(ls)));

console.timeEnd("M3 loop");
```

Result:

> ```
> M1 Unique 6,3,2,10,8,7,5,9,4,11,1
> M1 loop: 4.000ms
>
> M3 Unique 1,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
> M3 loop: 9.000ms
> ```

Answer (score 0):

After you have established that item [N-2] is distinct from [N-1], you should have added both of them to the results; instead, you only add [N-2].

In this case, `9` is the last element because sorting is done based on string value, so `'9' > '11'` for instance.

That said, to make the code somewhat easier, you should follow the following algorithm instead:

1. Add the first element always (unless array is empty)
2. Add subsequent elements if they're distinct from their predecessor

So:

```
function sortUnique(ls) 
{
    var results = [];

    if (!ls.length) {
        return results; 
    }

    ls.sort();
    results.push(ls[0]);

    for (var i = 1; i < ls.length; i++) {
        if (ls[i - 1] !== ls[i]) {
            results.push(ls[i]);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Also note that the passed array is sorted in place; if this is an issue, you may wish to make a shallow copy first.